# How can I do projection using Criteria in MongoDB?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, mongodb-query, database

Following is my Java controller method code

```
public List<MyClass> getStudentList(String studentName){
        studentName = ".*" + studentName + ".*";

    /*  BasicDBObject field = new BasicDBObject();
        field.put("regNo", 1);
        field.put("name", 1);
        field.put("collName", 1);
        field.put("deptName", 1);  */

        Query query = new Query(Criteria.where("name").regex(studentName, "i"));            

        return mongoTemplate.find(query,MyClass.class, COLLECTION_NAME);

    }
```

My Db looks like this

```
"regNo" : "1234", "name" : "ABCD", "collName" : "UNIVERSITY COLLEGE", "deptName" : "B.E. Computer Science and Engineering", "result" : [ { "subjCode" : "CS2251", "grade" : "E", "result" : "PASS", "subjName" : "Design and Analysis of Algorithms" }]
```

I want to select only regNo, name, collName and deptName. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this statement to **query**:

```
query.fields().include("regNo").include("name").include("collName").include("deptName").exclude("_id");
```

---

## APPEND

If your codes like:

```
public List<MyClass> getStudentList(String studentName){
    studentName = ".*" + studentName + ".*";

/*  BasicDBObject field = new BasicDBObject();
    field.put("regNo", 1);
    field.put("name", 1);
    field.put("collName", 1);
    field.put("deptName", 1);  */

    Query query = new Query(Criteria.where("name").regex(studentName, "i"));

    query.fields().include("regNo").include("name").include("collName").include("deptName").exclude("_id");

    return mongoTemplate.find(query,MyClass.class, COLLECTION_NAME);
}
```

It should be fine.

By the query string you provided as:

```
var q = {
        Query : {
            "name" : {
                "$regex" : ".*valueSearched.*",
                "$options" : "i"
            }
        },
        Fields : {
            "collName" : 1,
            "results" : 0,          // disallowed
            "_id" : 0,
            "de‚Äå‚ÄãptName" : 1,
            "name" : 1,
            "regNo" : 1
        }
    };
```

You actually perform something similar to

```
query.fields().include("collName").exclude("results").exclude("_id").include("de‚Äå‚ÄãptName").include("name").include("regNo");
```

instead.

Please check your code accordingly. Maybe you've called `query.fields().exculude("results")` somewhere; ELSE, it has a bug from some part. :)

The regulation for including and excluding fields are:

1. If you include some fields, then only return these fields and

   - "_id" will return implicitly;
   - only "_id" is allowed to exclude;
2. If you exclude some normal fields, other fields will returned and

   - can not include other fields;

Comment: How can I do count() or sum() on the above Criteria/Query?

Comment: @user3705478, You can find the method **count** in mongoTemplate.

Comment: Thanks. I can't double upvote. Should I use count() or sum(), to find our unique documents from the collection?

Comment: Is my pattern matching ' Pattern.matches("^[a-zA-Z]+") ' correct, if I want the user to enter only alphabets and spaces?

Comment: @user3705478, I corrected a mistake on **regulation** of the bottom of answer. (the second point)

Comment: @user3705478, That's not clear about your **unique** criteria.

Comment: @user3705478, I think 'Pattern.matches("^[a-zA-Z]{1}[a-z A-Z]*")' can find what you want. By the way, the comments is so long now. And this is not the style StackOverflow wants to. So you'd better post in other questions. Furthermore, if you use a model (such as mongoTemplate) frequently, you'd better learn it systematically first, that is more efficient for you.

Answer (score 1):

See here,it is deprecated but help you to understand

```
public DBCursor find(DBObject query,
                       DBObject fields,
                       int numToSkip,
                       int batchSize,
                       int options)
```

http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/DBCollection.html#find%28com.mongodb.DBObject,%20com.mongodb.DBObject,%20int,%20int%29

If you dont want any warning ,you may use  DBCursor Object.

```
public DBCursor(DBCollection collection,
        DBObject q,
        DBObject k,
        ReadPreference preference)
```

Initializes a new database cursor

Parameters:
    collection - collection to use
    q - query to perform
    k - keys to return from the query
    preference - the Read Preference for this query

I don't use java driver but it shouldn't be much difficult.

Comment: I don't want to use deprecated methods.

Comment: The second DBcursor is not deprecated.I just give you 2 solution. See http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/DBCursor.html#DBCursor%28com.mongodb.DBCollection,%20com.mongodb.DBObject,%20com.mongodb.DBObject,%20com.mongodb.ReadPreference%29

Answer (score 0):

For this issue you have to use `@JsonInclude(value=Include.NON_NULL)` in your pojo class like this:

```
@JsonInclude(value=Include.NON_NULL)

String id;
```